# Spring Roo Cardinality Mapped By attribute

Tags: jpa, entity-relationship, spring-roo, cardinality

I am trying to map an `Address` entity and a `Person` entity using a OneToMany mapping: "Each person has only one address but an Address can have many people".

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooEntity(identifierColumn = "addressID")
public class Address {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, **mappedBy = "address**")
    private Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<Person>();
}
```

I cannot figure out what to map the Address entity with (bold), i have very little experience with JPA(Eclipse Link) and Spring roo but i thought the `mappedBy should equal addressID` and for a bidirectional `ManyToOne` on my Person entity mappedBy should equal personID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As any JPA docs would tell you (all JPA implementations provide them), mappedBy is the name of the field of type "Address" in Person class. If you don't have a field of that type in Person, then the relation is not bidirectional and so you don't use "mappedBy"

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, how are then the two entities mapped? are they mapped by their unique ID's

Comment: Perhaps read a doc on a 1-N JPA relation, see http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/jpa/orm/one_to_many_collection.html  and select whether unidirectional or bidirectional and if using FK or Join table.